# List slicing out of index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "l"]
>>> a[30:]
[]
>>> a[:30]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'l']
```

I am trying to understand the logic behind this slicing. For example, when we try to reach element by indexing, it will give us an IndexError.

```
>>> a[12]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

We have got total 9 elements in the list. Yet, we can use any indexes which are greater than 8. Any technical explanations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The slice is well-defined but empty. The attempt to access an element that doesn't exist is undefined hence an error.

Answer (score 2):

This makes sense if you see a slice like `[i:j]` as "make a list of all elements that have an index between `i` and `j`." If the original list has 3 elements, `i` is 5 and `j` is 7, then there are no elements that fulfill this requirement, so the result will be an empty list.

In practice, it turns out this property is useful quite often.